# Is ts-node needed to run Jest in Next.js 14 with TypeScript

Tags: next.js, jestjs

I'm following the manual setup as described [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/testing/jest#manual-setup) to configure Jest in Next.js 14.1.3 with TypeScript.

When run `jest`, it complaints that 'ts-node' is required:

```
Error: Jest: Failed to parse the TypeScript config file C:\Users\dummy\playground\jest.config.ts
  Error: Jest: 'ts-node' is required for the TypeScript configuration files. Make sure it is installed
Error: Cannot find package 'ts-node' imported from C:\Users\dummy\playground\node_modules\jest-config\build\readConfigFileAndSetRootDir.js
```

However, the installation step did mention `ts-node`

```
npm install -D jest jest-environment-jsdom @testing-library/react @testing-library/jest-dom
```

Is this a documentation error or I'm missing something here?